# Resolve promise inside another promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm new to promises and having a bit of trouble grasping how to combine two promises together. I have a function which resolves a promise and does a few tasks:

```
loginService (context, credentials) {
  context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, credentials, { emulateJSON: true}).then(response => {
    this.user.authenticated = true
    localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_NAME, response.body[TOKEN_NAME])
  }).catch(response => {
    context.error = response.body
  })
},
```

And I want to modify the above code so that I can then do something like the following:

```
login () {
  this.submitButtonLoading = true
  loginService(this, this.credentials).then(response => {
    this.submitButtonLoading = false
    // Do something else here.
  }).catch(response => {
    this.submitButtonLoading = false
    // Do something else here.
  })
}
```

What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Your functions need `return` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return the promise** from `loginService`, then you can keep chaining:

```
loginService (context, credentials) {
  return context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, credentials, { emulateJSON: true})
    .then(response => {
      this.user.authenticated = true
      localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_STORAGE_NAME, response.body[TOKEN_NAME])
    })
    .catch(response => {
      context.error = response.body
    })
}

login () {
  this.submitButtonLoading = true
  loginService(this, this.credentials)
    .then(_ => {
      this.submitButtonLoading = false
      // ...
    })
}
```

Note that the `then()` function in `login` will always be executed, no matter whether the call succeeds or not.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I had tried that but couldn't differentiate whether it succeeds or not. Is there a way to handle whether it does?

Comment: @hatzipanis an otherwise uncaught error being thrown anywhere in the promise chain will propagate directly to a `catch` handler if present. Otherwise the error is silently swallowed, so always use `catch`.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks! Would you please be able to post an example?

Comment: To fix only calling the then handler in `login`, rethrow the error inside the first catch handler to trigger  the second catch inside `login`. In other words try inserting `throw response;` after `context.error=response.body;`

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much. Now to go study up a bit more on the inner workings of it all.

Answer (score 0):

To make loginService a promise, just return a `Promise` inside the function. Make sure to call `resolve` and/or `reject` when your function is fullfilled.

In your example, you can:

```
var loginService = function(context, credentials) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    context.$http.post(LOGIN_URL, credentials, {emlateJSON: true})
      .then(response => {
        if (success) {
          this.user.authenticated = true
          resolve(this.user)
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Log in failed'))
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
 }
```

Now it is then-able.

Notice the whole function is actually just return a big Promise. And also notice how a success or failure is resolved or rejected.

Comment: the [$http.post](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) method appears to return a promise already, which would make this something of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Traktor53 I started going down this route and realised it might be.